# Computing $-\hbar^2 \kappa^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\kappa^2 |x|) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \exp(-\kappa^2|x|)dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, distribution-theory

I am trying to compute
$$-\hbar^2 \kappa^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\kappa^2 |x|) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \exp(-\kappa^2|x|)dx$$

where $\kappa = \frac{\sqrt{m \alpha}}{\hbar}$. Thus far, I have defined $f(x) = \exp(-\kappa^2 |x|)$ and have asserted

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\exp(-\kappa^2 x) & : x > 0 \\ 
\exp(\kappa^2 x)  & : x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

to show

$$
\dot{f}(x)\begin{cases}
-\kappa^2 \exp(-\kappa^2 x) & : x > 0 \\ 
\kappa^2 \exp(\kappa^2 x)  & : x < 0
\end{cases}= \kappa^2 f(x) (-\text{sgn}(x))
$$

where I have been intentionally sloppy about the behavior of the system at $0$. (I am currently reading a physics textbook and the theory of distributions was never introduced in a rigorous context.) We have previously defined the step function as

$$
\theta(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & : x > 0 \\
0 & : x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

where (as the author stated) $\theta(0)$ is irrelevant.  Furthermore, I have already proven that $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \delta(x)$. In terms of this function,

$$
\dot{f}(x) = \kappa^2 f(x) (\theta(-x) - \theta(x))
$$

Thus, we integrate by parts (once again sloppily assuming that convergence is guaranteed and that the boundary conditions align).

$$
\begin{align}
-\hbar^2\kappa^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} dx &= -\hbar^2\kappa^2 \left[f(x) \frac{df}{dx}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \\
& - \hbar^2 \kappa^4 \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \frac{df}{dx} (\theta(-x) - \theta(x)) - f(x)^2 (\dot{\theta}(-x) + \dot{\theta}(x))dx\right] \\
& = - \hbar^2 \kappa^4 \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \kappa^2 f(x)^2 - f(x)^2 (\dot{\theta}(-x) + \dot{\theta}(x))dx\right] \\ 
& = - \hbar^2 \kappa^4 \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \kappa^2 f(x)^2 dx - 2 f(0)^2 \right] \\ 
& = - \hbar^2 \kappa^4 \left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \kappa^2 f(2x) dx - 2 \right] \\ 
& = 2 \left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2 - \hbar^2 \kappa^6 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(2x) dx \\
& = 2 \left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2 - 2 \hbar^2 \kappa^6 \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-2\kappa^2 x) dx \\ 
& = 2 \left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2 + \hbar^2 \kappa^4 \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-2\kappa^2 x) dx \\
& = 2 \left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2 - \hbar^2 \kappa^4\\
& = \left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

The book tells me that the correct answer is $\left(\frac{m \alpha}{\hbar}\right)^2$, so I assume my general approach is correct. How can I make the use of distributions more rigorous? How can I try to quantify asymptotic growth rates for $f(x)$? I even tried setting up a recursion relationship by introducing

$$I_{\alpha} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{\alpha}(x) \frac{d^2 f_{\alpha}}{dx^2} dx$$

where $f_{\alpha} (x) = \exp(-\alpha\kappa^2 |x|)$ and then trying to use a generating function to find series from

$$I_{2^n} = 2^n k^4 I_{2^{n+1}} + 2 \kappa^2$$

However, it did not appear to be particularly helpful. I feel that the book heavily suggested differentiating the Integrand, so I decided that I would either use Feynman's trick or integration by parts. The latter felt more natural given the second derivative in the middle of the integrand.

**Edit:** I should clarify that I am asking my question on Math SE (as opposed to Physics SE) because I deeply dissatisfied with the lack of mathematical explanation in the derivation. Does anyone have advice for making the use of distributions rigorous. Every time I say sloppily, is there a theorem or result I should quote? I have not yet had a formal course in the theory of distributions although I had to learn a little bit when I studied Green's functions in PDEs.

Are there any combinatorial approaches for describing distributions? I may be overzealous to apply generating functions, but I had hoped that they would provide bounds on more general wavefunctions that do not arise from simple potentials such as the delta function.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the situation far too complicated. We don't neet the theory of distributions. The integrand is an even function and $\kappa^2 >0.$ Let$c=\kappa^2.$ The integral is $$2\int_0^\infty e^{-cx}c^2e^{-cx}dx=2c^2\int_0^\infty e^{-2cx}dx$$ $$=\frac{2c^2}{2c}=c$$

Comment: How would I justify the definition of $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \delta(x)$ in a rigorous fashion without distributions? Could I use a generating function to characterize the asymptotic growth of the solution coefficients?

Comment: You can't say the integral is an "even" function without invoking the theory of distributions. There is no such function $f$ such that $f=\frac{d^2}{dx^2} e^{-\kappa |x|}$.

Comment: @Zachary: I said the "integrand" i,i.e. the function to be integrated is an even function. A ffunction $g$ is even if $g(-x) =g(x)$ for all $x$. Let $$g(x)=e^{-c|x|}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}(e^{-c|x|}).$$ . If $x \ge 0$ then $g(x)=e^{-cx}(-c)^2e^{-cx}=c^2e^{-2cx}=c^2e^{-2c|x|}$ and $g(-x)=c^2e^{2cx}=c^2e^{-2c|x|}$. Similar result if $x<0.$ There is no problem differentiating $e^{-c|x|}.$ Do the cases separately for positive and negative $x.$ If you are hesitant about $x=0$ you could integrate from from $a$ to $\infty$ for $a>0$ and take the limit as $a \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: When I take $a\to 0$ would I not have to justify the resulting integral using the theory of distributions. I do not wish to assume uniform continuity permitting me to interchange the order of the limit and integral as it had not been rigorously defined earlier in the textbook. Two problems earlier the book asked for a definition of the $\delta$-distribution in terms of a limit very similar to the one you have just described. I was taking this wikipedia article as inspiration for trying to introduce a rigorous definition in terms of distributions to the Cauchy principle value.

Comment: I ran out of space in my previous comment, so the page to which I am referring may be found here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory